# Can I connect to 2 seperate mqtt brokers without a bridge between them and subscibe/ publish accordingly?

Tags: mqtt

I am willing to create a mediator which is subscribed and published to 2 separate broker who have no access to topics of each other. The aim is to updates and create a logic of the message published by broker 1 and send it to broker 2 according to the set of rules

Do I need 2 separate ports ? As the topic level might be different in both brokers

Any help is much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no MQTT standard (note, can only speak for `3.1.1`) defined features that would allow a client maintain two concurrent connections. Therefore, this is entirely broker implementation-dependent and necessitates a bridge.

For example, the Eclipse Mosquitto broker can be configured as a bridge to another broker and even remap topics from itself to a different topic structure of the other. Please refer to the Mosquitto [man page](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html) section `Configuring Bridges` for the specifics.

As far as creating a bespoke application, you can always write a simple Python program that is running two instances of an MQTT client ([Eclipse Paho](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/) for example, which has a lightweight `asyncio` wrapper to facilitate concurrency), each connected to different brokers. The glue logic between them just has to re-publish an incoming subscribed topic message from `Broker A` to some topic, with or without a remapping step, to `Broker B`.

If the two brokers are both running locally on a single NIC, then you would need to use different ports.